# How to fix Javascript code adding 2 tax variables

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript.
I have a form that I need to add a second sales tax variable to.

`#q93_tax2` is the new input field I created, I cannot seem to add `#q93_tax2` + `#q92_tax1`.

How do I add `#q93_tax2` and `#q92_tax1` to get a combined tax to multiply by the total?

```
#set( $D = '$' )
 <script>
${D}(document).ready(function()
{
  $(document).on('change', '.tab-pane, .totals', function() {
var quantity1, price1, lineTotal1;
var quantity2, price2, lineTotal2;
var quantity3, price3, lineTotal3;
var quantity4, price4, lineTotal4;
var quantity5, price5, lineTotal5;
var subTotal,subT1, subT2, subT3, subT4, subT5;
var tax, tatal;
quantity1 = $(' #q30_quantity1 ').val()||0;
price1 = $(' #q34_price1 ').val()||0;
lineTotal1 = (parseFloat(quantity1)) * (parseFloat(price1))||0.00;
$(' #q85_total1 ').val(lineTotal1.toFixed(2));
$(' #q34_price1 ').val(parseFloat(price1).toFixed(2));

quantity2 = $(' #q30_quantity2 ').val()||0;
price2 = $(' #q34_price2 ').val()||0;
lineTotal2 = (parseFloat(quantity2)) * (parseFloat(price2))||0.00;
$(' #q85_total2 ').val(lineTotal2.toFixed(2));
$(' #q34_price2 ').val(parseFloat(price2).toFixed(2));

quantity3 = $(' #q30_quantity3 ').val()||0;
price3 = $(' #q34_price3 ').val()||0;
lineTotal3 = (parseFloat(quantity3)) * (parseFloat(price3))||0.00;
$(' #q85_total3 ').val(lineTotal3.toFixed(2));
$(' #q34_price3 ').val(parseFloat(price3).toFixed(2));

quantity4 = $(' #q30_quantity4 ').val()||0;
price4 = $(' #q34_price4 ').val()||0;
lineTotal4 = (parseFloat(quantity4)) * (parseFloat(price4))||0.00;
$(' #q85_total4 ').val(lineTotal4.toFixed(2));
$(' #q34_price4 ').val(parseFloat(price4).toFixed(2));

quantity5 = $(' #q30_quantity5 ').val()||0;
price5 = $(' #q34_price5 ').val()||0;
lineTotal5 = (parseFloat(quantity5)) * (parseFloat(price5))||0.00;
$(' #q85_total5 ').val(lineTotal5.toFixed(2));
$(' #q34_price5 ').val(parseFloat(price5).toFixed(2));

subT1 = $(' #q85_total1 ').val()||0;
subT2 = $(' #q85_total2 ').val()||0;
subT3 = $(' #q85_total3 ').val()||0;
subT4 = $(' #q85_total4 ').val()||0;
subT5 = $(' #q85_total5 ').val()||0;
subTotal = parseFloat(subT1) + parseFloat(subT2) + 
parseFloat(subT3) + parseFloat(subT4) + parseFloat(subT5);
$(' #q90_subtotal1 ').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));

tax = $(' #q92_tax1 ').val()||0 + $(' #q93_tax2 ').val()||0;
total = (parseFloat(tax)/100) * subTotal + subTotal;
$(' #q94_totalSale ').val(total.toFixed(2));
  });

${D}('#request-form')[0].reset();
${D}("#save_btn").button('reset');
});
```

Comment: `var totalTax = $('#q93_tax2').val() + $('#q92_tax1').val()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually looks like this to the parser

```
tax = ($('#q92_tax1').val()) || (0 + $('#q93_tax2').val() ) || 0;
```

Another issue is val() is a string so you are adding strings together.

```
tax = (Number($('#q92_tax1').val()) || 0) + (Number($('#q93_tax2').val()) || 0);
```

Comment: tax = (Number($('#q92_tax1').val()) || 0) + (Number($('#q93_tax2').val()) || 0);           
This Worked! Thank you tonnes! I owe you a beer @epascarello!